# How to display colon in a text field?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to display following output:
   NAME    : ***_*__*_*__*_***
    USN    : ***_*__*_*__*_***
ADDRESS    : ***_*__*_*__*_***

I TRIED BY PLACING 3 TEXT VIEW..BUT : IS  NOT WORKING. CAN ANYONE HELP ME PLEASE
HERE'S THE CODE:
                     /*xml file*/

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.assignment3.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/name" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/colon1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:text="@string/colon1"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:hint="@string/edit_name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usn"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:text="@string/usn" />
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/colon2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:text="@string/colon2"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_usn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/edit_usn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/usn"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:hint="@string/add" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/colon3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:text="@string/colon3"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_add"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/usn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hint="@string/edit_add" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/submit"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Only first colon is visible..Y other 2 colons are not displaying?

```
              /*layout file*/

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Student Application Form</string>
    <string name="name">NAME</string>
    <string name="colon1">:</string>
    <string name="edit_name">Enter your Name</string>
    <string name="usn">USN</string>
    <string name="colon2">:</string>
    <string name="edit_usn">Enter the Usn</string>
    <string name="add">ADDRESS</string>
    <string name="colon3">:</string>
    <string name="edit_add">Enter the Address</string>
    <string name="submit">Submit</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: all three fields in a separate line

Comment: You are using Relative layout..Your Views are no relations with others...try place your Views Correctly..

Comment: You can also do it like this `<string name="name">NAME : </string>` why you are using 2 string for that. and also you can reuse colon1 no need of colon2 and colon3

Comment: because all 3 :n's should come exactly one below the other..

Comment: @sangeetha your alignment of views are not right.

Comment: @sangeetha take a look at my post. How yours look and the one i posted

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.assignment3.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="NAME : " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/edit_name" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/usn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="USN :" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_usn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/edit_usn" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ADDRESS :" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_add"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/edit_add"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just got to `design` view of you xml file and double click on the component whose text you want to set it will show you a popup window enter you text there. That would be better for you..

Answer (score 1):

How your layout looked. I changed colon to `android:text="1..."/>` similalr `2...` and `3...` for other textview's to show what is wrong in yours

[image]

You need to align and arrange view properly

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.assignment3.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="NAME" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="@string/colon1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:text="ADDRESS" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="@string/colon1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="USN" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="@string/colon1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You need not have 3 strings in string.xml for `:`. You can simple refer to the same string colon1 many times.

Your problem was the textview not aligned properly. One of the textview was overlayed by another and it looked invisible.

Note: I hard coded strings for testing purpose

Snap:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="NAME" />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.9"
        android:text=":" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="name" />
</LinearLayout>
```

the colon is set on seperate textview with weight as 1.9. Repeat this layout for USN and Address. Now the colon will be displayed in uniformity.